# Can JavaScript be used entirely to make a SQL querying app?

Tags: javascript

There's a specific app that I want to make, and I was wondering if I can use JavaScript to code it entirely.

Comment: You can learn [AngularJS](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of frameworks out there that let you write your code in HTML, CSS, and JS and then compile/build apps to native devices I for instance [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/) do this.

Answer (score 1):

Choices are countless. Try Cordova for hybrid app development.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely thinking of a single page HTML5-based "app".
(though it's arguably not an app, it's just a web page).
These are often built using frameworks such as Angular, Backbone, or Ember.

Watch out, there's still constant debate on the merits of HTML5 vs. native apps.